# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable | Forza horizon 4 Telemetry

Tags: python, udp, nonetype, telemetry

I try to make an ia on Forza Horizon 4 so I try to receive the telemetry info but it don't work.

The Code :

```
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


#formats of data loaded in
default_format = '<iI27f4i20f5i'

# Dash format (FM7)
dash_format = default_format + '17fH6B3b'

# Horizon format (FH4+)
horizon_format = default_format + 'i19fH6B4b'

MSEC_TO_MPH = 2.236936


unpacked = None
loopNum = 0
windowOpen = True
FONT = ("Consolas", 15)
def getData():
    global unpacked
    #for i in range(200):
    while windowOpen:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        unpacked = struct.unpack(horizon_format, data)

#Update the data visualization with a delay
def updateData():
    global unpacked
    global loopNum
    while windowOpen:
        loopNum += 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
        
        #only update info when game is unpaused
        if unpacked[0] == 1:
            RPMVar.set("RPM: {:.0f}".format(unpacked[4]))
            GearVar.set("Gear: " + str(unpacked[84]))
            SpeedVar.set("Speed: {:>3.0f} MPH".format(unpacked[64]*MSEC_TO_MPH))
            RaceTimeVar.set("Time: " + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=unpacked[77]))[:-4])
            CurrLapVar.set("Current Lap: " + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=unpacked[76]))[:-4])
            BestLapVar.set("Best Lap: " + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=unpacked[74]))[:-3])
            PrevLapVar.set("Last Lap: " + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=unpacked[75]))[:-3])
            try:
                RPMBar.set(unpacked[4] / unpacked[2])
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass
            if RPMBar.get() > 0.9:
                RPMBar.configure(progress_color="red")
            else:
                RPMBar.configure(progress_color="#1f6aa5")
```

I have this error :

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "C:\Users\lytox\Desktop\fh4 deeplearning\ForzaTelemetry-main\Dash.py", line 55, in updateData
    if unpacked[0] == 1:
       ~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I Want to get my telemetry info, i tried many code, in some code i don't receve anytrhing but i don't have any error in other i have error. This is really anoying...

Comment: `unpacked` is `None`. I don't know the flow of your code, but it suggests that `unpacked = struct.unpack(horizon_format, data)` wasn't executed. Maybe that means that function (I guess its a function?) wasn't called, or `while windowOpen:` was `False` so didn't run.

Comment: I post the firsdt part

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Your code, when copied and run *without changes*, should reproduce the problem.